# How can I check whether a gameObject is contained in a list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to check weather a hole is full or empty, by comparing the transform position of both Cylinders and Holes. Note that I can't simply do `else if (cylpos != holpos)` as I need it to be that way. It also seems that `if (!fullHoles.Contains(hole))` doesn't work as I want it to.

```
        foreach (GameObject hole in Holes)
    {
        holpos = hole.transform.position;

        foreach (GameObject cylinder in Cylinders)
        {
            cylpos = cylinder.transform.position;

            if (cylpos == holpos)
            {
                fullHoles.Add(hole);
            }
        }
        if (!fullHoles.Contains(hole))
        {
            emptyHoles.Add(hole);
            Debug.Log(hole);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why `fullHoles.Contains` should not do the trick here.

**But** note that the [Vector3 `== operator`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) uses a precision of `0.00001` for equality meaning it does the same as

```
if(Vector3.Distance(cylpos, holpos) < 0.00001f)
```

I don't know how exactly you move the according objects but it is very unlikely that a moved GameObject will exactly match a position with that precision on runtime.

So I can only guess that the objects where not added to `fullholes` the way you expected.

---

You should probably rather use

```
[SerializeField] private float threshold = 0.1f;

...

if(Vector3.Distance(cylpos, holpos) < threshold)
```

and adjust the `threshold` via the Inspector according to your needs

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why I didn't say this in the initial question, but using !fullholes.Contains returns all of the holes in fullholes, which is counter intuitive. Also, using simply fullholes.Contains returns nothing at all, which is also very strange. I'll see what I can do.